# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '1' of object '

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I will start by saying: **I know that this question have been asked several times here on the site.**

I'm still asking because not all of the errors i found matched mine, and all of them didn't stem from the same reasons, so at the end of it, i still remained with no clue for any solution.

Now, for the problem itself:

I have a React app,
and i have this object:

```
let Ellipse = {
  radii: ['', ''],
  coordinates: ['', ''],
  tilt: ['']
}
```

The object is defined outside the main function, which means that the program looks something like this:

```
let Ellipse = {
  radii: ['', ''],
  coordinates: ['', ''],
  tilt: ['']
}

export default function App() {
  const handleForm = (e) => {
      Ellipse.coordinates[0] = parseInt(e.target.value);
}

return (
<TextField required onChange={handleForm}/>
);}
```

The problem is that on the first time when i try to wirte something on the textfield everything is fine, but on the second time it's just getting freaked out, and the console (on the chrome dev tools) is coming out with the error that i've mentioned in the title:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'*

**PLS HELP!**

Comment: Might be due to `Ellipse` starting with a capital letter, or the fact that `coordinates` is type `string[]` but you try to assign a `number` to one of it's indices

Comment: Already tried both of the suggestions.
Didn't work

Comment: Please show your entire code. It sounds very much like somewhere you have a `Ellipse.coordinates = String(Ellipse.coordinates)` or `Ellipse.coordinates += ''` or similar that assigns the string `'[object Array]'` to `Ellipse.coordinates`. Or alternatively, does something like `Object.freeze(Ellipse.coordinates)`, although then I'd expect a different error message.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no point. I've literally wiped out all of the code in my project and wrote this exact same code you saw above. Still getting this goddamn error